# installing a local module using npm and then use it in requirement statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

When I want to install a local package , I can use the command bellow:

```
npm install </path_of_package>
```

But if I want to use it then in a requirement statement , how should I do?
For example if I have downloaded the last alpha version of [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) that is not yet avalaible with the classic npm installation , how can I launch a script that use the statement bellow?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

Comment: What is your question? On the github project of puppeteer, it looks like there is a npm package!

Comment: @3Dos not with the last merged version

Comment: How did you "install" it then ? All you have to do is to find the export module and require it by its path.

Answer (score 0):

just install the npm Module in you project folder then you can use it.

```
npm i puppeteer
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I found i have to write the installation folder in require :

```
const puppeteer = require(<path local installation>);
```

For example

```
const puppeteer = require('./');
```